# Css background image not resolving

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to select header-logo I tried the following selector suggested by css selector

```
body > div > div.header-logo
{
    background-image: url("logo.png");


}
```

For the html of the below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

    <body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-text">100+ Years Of Combiend Industry Expierence</div>

<div class="header-logo"></div>                   

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

But when I view it in chrome it is showing unresolved

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the `>` sign to track the element you just use space when its element and use `.` if its sub element

```
example : body div.header-logo
```

you can find useful tutorial for css [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_syntax.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```css
div>div.header-logo
{
    background-image: url("https://tproger.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/stack-overflow-logo-2.png");
    width: 720px;
    height: 270px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

    <body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-text">100+ Years Of Combiend Industry Expierence</div>

<div class="header-logo"></div>                   

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

but, if you wont add a logo, correct do this:

```html
<div class="header-logo">
  <img src="logo.png" alt="It's a logo">
</div>
```